# how to fix build.gradle for map application on android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am developing a basic map example but I'm in trouble with android studio.

I got this error :

```
Error:(9, 0) Cause: startup failed:build file 'C:\Users\Tugrul\AndroidStudioProjects\ServiceTextSender\build.gradle': 9: expecting '}', found ':' @ line 9, column 31.
    compile ‘com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+’1 error
```

And here an error resource from my build.gradle file(dependencies :

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
    compile ‘com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+’
    compile ‘com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.36′

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

How can I fix this? Could you help me please? I'm in trouble with Android Studio. I'm in trouble with this error.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is character error. ' and ‘ are different.
Try change this :

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
compile ‘com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+’
compile ‘com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.36′
```

to this

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.36'
```

Edit:

These are gradle Files:

[image]

You need to add your

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.36'
}
```

lines to Module Specific build.gradle file shown as above.

Comment: I'll change like you said, it look like good but the android studio said when i tried run the project "Error running app: Gradle project sync failed. Please fix your project and try again". Android Studio is completely  trouble maker. Could you look this? Can I share my Activity class? Thank you.

Comment: @m.tuğrul now I realize it, your gradle file is wrong. Other answer says right. You need to add "complie" lines to your module's gradle file

Comment: I didn't get it what you say? could you explain more clearly please? could you show? I need help? If you are Turkish could you explain on Turkish?

Comment: @m.tuğrul It is simple, you are editing the wrong gradle file. There are two gradle file types exist. For Project and for the Modules. You need to edit gradles inside your module.

Comment: Will I edit build.gradle file like your answer? How can I path of build.gradle file for the modules? Is it in android studio file?

Comment: @m.tuğrul see my edited answer. I didn't respond in Turkish, because the global language here is English.

Comment: thank you, I solve this but I got another errors I'll be crazy because of android studio. I shoose minimum sdk api 19 but it choose target 23, when create application I couldn't see choose target sdk. I'll be crazy because of Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

**Regarding the error:**
Looks like you are adding this to the wrong gradle file, should be added to the app's gradle file (the one in the app's folder), not the module (the top one). The top one specifies the gradle plugin to use and as you have it listed here, I'm assuming you are editing the wrong build-gradle file.
If you instead check in the same directory that *contains* the src-folder (*not inside* src) you will find the app's dependencies section where you can add that line.

And/Or you are just using the wrong characters should be `'` and not `‘`.

**Suggested easier solution:**
Create a new Google Map Activity using the template when starting a new project, or right click in your project package and choose (in the popup menu):

```
New -> Google -> Google Maps Activity
```

And everything will be set up for you.

Comment: thank you, I solved this now, but I got an another error' I don't understand. I changed build.gradle file and it look like good. But now, android studio says "Error running app: Gradle project sync failed. Please fix your project and try again" when I start the app. Top of file(where Iwe see file names f.e MyActivitiy.java) redline,it mean is error but don't show bug on any line. I'll be crazy. Thank you so much.

Comment: Did you remove this from your file and moved it to the other gradle file? You get error messages in the messages tab (see bottom of android studio and click "messages" and scoll). If this answer solved your (initial) problem please accept the answer.

Comment: I solved this, thank you, Now, I apply a some example from the internet and owner of internet developed his example on android studio and I'm developing on android studio, but I got an error and I'm crazy. What you I don't know but eclipse is better than android studio. faster and simple than android studio.